# Android extends two classes in same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-maps-v2, android-sliding

In my Android application, I need slider menu navigation (like Facebook) and map in same activity. For slider menu I have a code that main class extends `SlidingFragmentActivity` and map I extend `FragmentActivity`. My question is How can I extends both class in same activity for using sliding menu and map.

Comment: Why not use a NavigationDrawer?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by extending class.

```
class SliderMenuActivity extends FragmentActivity{

....
}
```

and

```
MyClass extends SliderMenuActivity {
 ......
}
```

now `MyClass` is sub class of `FragmentActivity`

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As java doesn't support multiple inheritance, it is not possible to extend multiple classes by a single class.

In order to achieve your goal you can do something different. 
You can use a parent activity. And inside of that activity you can define 2 different fragment for for 2 different purpose.

```
public class JoblistFragment extends Fragment implements OnScrollListener {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             .....
             return rootView;
        }
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                      .........
                      ....

                }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "slider menu navigation (like Facebook)" that you are referring to, is in fact a [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). The official documentation is describing how to implement it with full detail. You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

In summary, you will create a layout in xml like below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, setup is required in your Activity (see the provided link for a full reference). The final result will be as below figures show.

Open:

[image: Open]

Closed:

[image: Closed]